# ifelse do nothing in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I'm a very novice R programmer, and I'm trying to convert old SAS code to R.  I need to replace values based on a condition, and if the condition is false, leave them alone. I've googled this and tried many of the solutions posted, but to no avail.   The reason I'm doing this is to categorize the first instance of an event (in this case physicians writing a prescription). if the first month they wrote a prescription was May of last year, their beginning month(newwriter) is 5.  If it was in June, then 6 etc.  I'm working backwards from June of this year, and I want to update their beginning month(newwriter) if an earlier prescription is found.  If no earlier prescription is found, I want to leave the number alone.  This is the code I'm using:

```
newwriters$newwriter=ifelse(newwriters$MTRx_06_30_2017>0,18,NULL)
newwriters$newwriter=ifelse(newwriters$MTRx_05_31_2017>0,17,NULL)
newwriters$newwriter=ifelse(newwriters$MTRx_04_30_2017>0,16,NULL)
newwriters$newwriter=ifelse(newwriters$MTRx_03_31_2017>0,15,NULL)
newwriters$newwriter=ifelse(newwriters$MTRx_02_28_2017>0,14,NULL)
newwriters$newwriter=ifelse(newwriters$MTRx_01_31_2017>0,13,NULL)
newwriters$newwriter=ifelse(newwriters$MTRx_12_31_2016>0,12,NULL)
newwriters$newwriter=ifelse(newwriters$MTRx_11_30_2016>0,11,NULL)
newwriters$newwriter=ifelse(newwriters$MTRx_10_31_2016>0,10,NULL)
```

The problem is that it keeps changing higher values to 0 if it doesn't find a prescription in that month.  I want it to just leave the values alone. I've tried all of the following as well with no success:

```
newwriters$newwriter=ifelse(newwriters$MTRx_06_30_2017>0,18,newwriters$newwriter)
newwriters$newwriter=ifelse(newwriters$MTRx_06_30_2017>0,18,newwriters[,16])
newwriters$newwriter=ifelse(newwriters$MTRx_06_30_2017>0,18,)
```

As I mentioned, I'm new to writing R code.  I'm sure there's a better/faster/more efficient way of doing this, but I'm not sure what else to try. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why not using `if(){}` instead of `ifelse()`?

Comment: because I get the vector error if i use if(){}.  

"In if (newwriters$MTRx_06_30_2017 > 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: And that's when `apply` helps you.

Comment: If you repeat basically the same line that often your code is suboptimal. You should completely rewrite this instead of following SAS so literally. Probably you also should reshape your data. R is totally different from SAS. PS: You most certainly don't want to assign NULL here.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `apply`, but I'll do some research, thanks!

Comment: Thanks Roland, do you have any suggestions of a better way to code this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to change a column (or vector) conditionally, and leave entries untouched where the condition is not satisfied, you could probably also do without `ifelse`.

Consider the following two vectors:

```
a = c(1,2,3,4,5)
b = c(1,1,1,1,1)
```

Now, let's say we want to replace values in `b` with `2`, if the value in `a` is larger than `3`. Here are two ways to achieve what you want:

```
b[a>2] = 2
b = ifelse(a>3,2,b)
```

They will both result in `b` being `1 1 2 2 2`. However, now let's replace one of the values in `a`, with `NA`, let's say;

```
a = c(1,2,NA,4,5)
```

Now, compare the results of the following two snippets:

```
b = c(1,1,1,1,1)
b[a>2] = 2
# 1 1 1 2 2
```

and

```
b = c(1,1,1,1,1)
b = ifelse(a>3,2,b)
# 1  1 NA  2  2
```

The intuitive reason for this is that `NA>3`returns not `TRUE` or `FALSE`, but `NA`, so `ifelse` does not know which of the two fields to return. When doing `b[a>2]`, we only replace values where `a>2` is `TRUE`, and since `NA` is not `TRUE`, the value for the third entry is simply not altered.

---

So in your specific case,

```
writers$newwriter=ifelse(newwriters$MTRx_06_30_2017>0,18,newwriters$newwriter)
```

probably does not work as expected because there are there NULL or NA values in those columns. If you want to use `ifelse`, you could do something like:

```
writers$newwriter=ifelse(newwriters$MTRx_06_30_2017>0 & !is.na(newwriters$MTRx_06_30_2017),18,newwriters$newwriter)
```

but you might also consider doing

```
writers$newwriter[newwriters$MTRx_06_30_2017>0] = 18
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I do have NA values in the columns.  I added your solution and it worked as I had intended!.  Could you tell me why it works so I have a better understanding going forward?

Comment: of course. You were comparing values that were NA, to check if they  were larger than a certain value. Try the following in R: NA>1. You'll see that it doesn't return FALSE, but it returns NA! So your code does not know what to do. Hope this has helped! Would you please consider accepting my answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Better is to use `if_else` from package **dplyr**. It has an explicit treatment for `NA`s which make it more robust and it is also slightly faster.

Quick example:

```
> library(tidyverse)
> iris2 = iris %>% as_data_frame()
> 
> #add some NA's
> iris2$Sepal.Length[c(1, 5, 8)] = NA
> 
> #print
> iris2
# A tibble: 150 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1        NA           3.50         1.40       0.200 setosa 
 2         4.90        3.00         1.40       0.200 setosa 
 3         4.70        3.20         1.30       0.200 setosa 
 4         4.60        3.10         1.50       0.200 setosa 
 5        NA           3.60         1.40       0.200 setosa 
 6         5.40        3.90         1.70       0.400 setosa 
 7         4.60        3.40         1.40       0.300 setosa 
 8        NA           3.40         1.50       0.200 setosa 
 9         4.40        2.90         1.40       0.200 setosa 
10         4.90        3.10         1.50       0.100 setosa 
# ... with 140 more rows
> 
> #conditionally change
> iris2$new_var = if_else(iris2$Sepal.Length > 5, true = 100, false = 0, missing = -100)
> 
> iris2$new_var
  [1] -100    0    0    0 -100  100    0 -100    0    0  100    0    0    0  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100    0  100    0    0    0
 [28]  100  100    0    0  100  100  100    0    0  100    0    0  100    0    0    0    0  100    0  100    0  100    0  100  100  100  100
 [55]  100  100  100    0  100  100    0  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100
 [82]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100    0  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100    0  100
[109]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100
[136]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100
```

So, we made a new variable where values above 5 changed to 100, below 5 to 0, and `NA` into -100.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. TLDR: `missing = value` is written when checker comes across a NA (missing) value. **NOTE**  `if_else()` is a part of the **dplyr** package.